# Rectangle Intersect Ball on a Square

Tags: c#, xna, intersect

I am making a Game like Peggle Deluxe using `C#` and `XNA` for learning.

I have two rectangles, a ball, and a square field. The ball gets shot out of a cannon and if the ball hits the square, the square disappears and the ball flies away, but the ball doesn't spring off realistically; it sometimes flies away in a different direction or gets stuck on the edge.

This is my code at the moment:

```
public void Update(Ball b, Deadline dl) 
    { 

        ArrayList listToDelete = new ArrayList(); 
        foreach (Field aField in allFields) 
        { 
            if (aField.square.Intersects(b.ballhere)) 
            { 
                listToDelete.Add(aField); 
                Punkte = Punkte + 100; 

                float distanceX = Math.Abs(b.ballhere.X - aField.square.X); 
                float distanceY = Math.Abs(b.ballhere.Y - aField.square.Y); 

                if (distanceX < distanceY) 
                { 
                    b.myMovement.X = -b.myMovement.X; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    b.myMovement.Y = -b.myMovement.Y; 
                } 

            } 
        }
```

It changes the X or Y axis depending on how the ball hits the square but not always.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: You would likely get better responses [posting over on Gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Not an answer however I am curious as to why you are using XNA? It is unfortunately no longer being updated by Microsoft, and if you are interested in Game development, I couldn't recommend UNITY enough.

Comment: Should the line read "if (distanceX > distanceY)" ?

Comment: @Glitch100 I know but our Teacher wanted thad we use it to learn different Envoirements.

Comment: @Glitch100 - quite false. Google "MonoGame", which is XNA's new name (Being developed as a open-source public project now, instead of a commercial Microsoft thing) - also Unity is for 3D stuff, not so great with 2D.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva Exactly it's open source, it's no longer a Microsoft Thing. And Unity is great for 2D there are some excellent things out there to use. So what I said was not false as Microsoft AREN'T updating it.

Comment: @Glitch100 - okay yeah technically not false. But you were implying that XNA is dead / shouldn't be used - which is false. You also implied and now directly stated that Unity is a potential replacement for XNA and it simply isn't - Unity is not 2D-friendly. It /can/ do 2D, but not well, or fast, or form-like.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking

```
if (distanceX < distanceY)
```

to detect which side of your square is being hit, if I got it.
So, I think your problem is when the ball hits the square near the corners, when your `distanceX` and `distanceY` are quite the same and your collision detection fails. You need a more accurate way to check the collision in that case.